# scylladb : scylla_io_setup script not showing Recommended --max-io-requests param in output

Tags: scylla

### I am running scylla_io_setup script inside docker container, i have mounted /var/lib/scylla/ data directory to 1TB xfs sdd. the scylla_io_setup not showing Recommended --max-io-requests parameter in output. following is the output of the script.

```
[root@ip /]# ./usr/lib/scylla/scylla_io_setup 
tuning /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4
tuning: /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4/queue/nomerges 2
warning: unable to tune /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4/queue/nomerges to 2

tuning /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:2:4/0:2:4:0/block/sde
tuning: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:2:4/0:2:4:0/block/sde/queue/nomerges 2
warning: unable to tune /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:2:4/0:2:4:0/block/sde/queue/nomerges to 2

tuning /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4
tuning /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4
tuning /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4
tuning /sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-4
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARN  2020-01-29 10:26:47,892 [shard 0] seastar - Unable to set SCHED_FIFO scheduling policy for timer thread; latency impact possible. Try adding CAP_SYS_NICE
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
WARNING: unable to mbind shard memory; performance may suffer: 
INFO  2020-01-29 10:26:48,161 [shard 0] iotune - /var/lib/scylla/saved_caches passed sanity checks
WARN  2020-01-29 10:26:48,161 [shard 0] iotune - Scheduler for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:2:4/0:2:4:0/block/sde/queue/scheduler set to deadline. It is recommend to set it to noop before evaluation so as not to skew the results.
WARN  2020-01-29 10:26:48,161 [shard 0] iotune - nomerges for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:02:00.0/host0/target0:2:4/0:2:4:0/block/sde/queue/nomerges set to 0. It is recommend to set it to 2 before evaluation so that merges are disabled. Results can be skewed otherwise.
Starting Evaluation. This may take a while...
Measuring sequential write bandwidth: 188 MB/s
Measuring sequential read bandwidth: 424 MB/s
Measuring random write IOPS: 23843 IOPS
Measuring random read IOPS: 66322 IOPS
Writing result to /etc/scylla.d/io_properties.yaml
Writing result to /etc/scylla.d/io.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Was the result written to io.conf?

Comment: yes result is written in io.conf file . result=>       cat /etc/scylla.d/io_properties.yaml 
disks:
  - mountpoint: /var/lib/scylla
    read_iops: 67075
    read_bandwidth: 446294752
    write_iops: 23634
    write_bandwidth: 224162560